# 'Linq to Entities does not recognize the method' when ordering by Object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have seen many SO questions surrounding this topic but I cant find the solution to my particular situation, I have the following statement:

```
return (from Animals in ctx.Animals
                orderby sortStrategy.Sort(Animals)
               descending
                select Animals).AsQueryable();
```

sortStrategy.Sort just returns the Object that I want to sort Animals by. However this throws the following error:

'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object Sort(AnimalLibrary.Animal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I believe this is because Linq doesn't understand how to execute sortStrategy.Sort, but im not sure how to actually fix this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, James.

Comment: `sortStrategy.Sort` returns a System.Type?

Comment: @Alberto yes it does:)

Comment: This will never work, you should pass a member name to the `order by` clause: `order by Animals.SomeProperty`

Comment: I have just changed this, it was a silly mistake I made, however it still throws the error, it just slightly different now, Edited the question in light of this. :)

Comment: orderby needs a property to order by, e.g. Animals.PropertyX

Comment: It has, it the .Sort passes back the object(Animals.Name) for example

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is impossible. Linq to entities does not atcually execute your code, it just uses the syntax tree to build sql. The thing you are trying to do only works with linq to objects.

Comment: Return a List<Animals> first then do the sort.

Comment: @alun If it isnt possible, could you perhaps point me in the right direction to make it work? I am really stuck on this, and I dont know where to go from here.

Comment: If you want to fetch the data to memory and do the sorting there, probably `(from Animals in ctx.Animals.AsEnumerable() /* NB! */
                orderby sortStrategy.Sort(Animals)
               descending
                select Animals)` will work.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen this is the perfect answer for this question, would you mind making an answer out of your comment so I can mark it as the accepted answer? thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer was promoted from a comment.)

If you want to fetch the data to memory and do the sorting there, probably

```
(from Animals in ctx.Animals.AsEnumerable() /* NB! */
orderby sortStrategy.Sort(Animals) descending
select Animals)
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, this will not work. When you pass a query to Linq-To-Entities, it translates that query into SQL - it requires that everything you pass it in the query can be translated to SQL as-is - it will not execute arbitrary C# methods in order to obtain a value which it can then embed in the SQL it produces.

If you want to order by `Animal` name, your query will have to include `order by Animals.Name`. If you want to order by the result of `sortStrategy.Sort` you'll either have to execute the query without sorting then perform the sorting on the results in memory using Linq-To-Objects, or use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to embed the result of `sortStrategy.Sort()` in a string query which can then be translated into an expression.

Comment: Would it be possible to use something like: 
List<Animal> animals = (from Animals in ctx.Animals select Animals).ToList(); Then use animals.Sort() on the list?

I dont really use Linq that much, is it possible to sort the list I get back by my sortStrategy.Sort() result?

Comment: @JamesZeinzu You can use `AsEnumerable()` rather than `ToList()` to avoid building a list out of it, but yes, that should work.

Comment: Enumerables only have the OrderBy method, so I dont know if it would work like that, all I really need is an example of how to actually use .Sort or .OrderBy with my sortStrategy.Sort() result.

Comment: Yep, that would work - that's the second option I mentioned using Linq-To-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You say `sortStrategy.Sort` returns some property of the `Animal`, so you may be able to redefine your strategy class as something like

```
class SortStrategy<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<Animal, T>> Sort { get; set; }
}
```

then build up your strategies like

```
var sortByAgeStrategy = new SortStrategy<int> { Sort = a => a.Age };
var sortByNameStrategy = new SortStrategy<string> { Sort = a => a.Name };
```

at which point you can pick one of these strategies and call LINQ like

```
IQueryable<Animal> sorted =
    from a in animals
    orderby someSortStrategy.Sort descending
    select a;
```